# Ladder operators in $x$, $y$ and $z$ directions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, commutator

I want to use ladder operators to express $x \times p$

Expressing  $p_i$ as $(a_i^+ - a_i)$ and $x_j$ as $(a_j^+ + a_j)$ and getting commutator
which of the commutators of $a_i^+ \times a_i^+ ,a_i \times a_j , a-i \times a_j$ and $a_i^+ \times a_j$ are non zero?

Answer (score 1):

In general

$$
[x_i,x_j] = [p_i,p_j] = 0 ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ [x_i,p_j] = i\delta_{ij}
$$

so if you define

$$
a_j = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x_j + i p_j) ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ a^\dagger_j = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x_j - i p_j)
$$

you can get for instance

\begin{eqnarray}
[a_j, a_k] &=& \frac{1}{2}[x_j + i p_j, x_k + ip_k] \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}([x_j,x_k] + i[x_j, p_k] + i [p_j,x_k]-[p_j,p_k]) \\
&=& \frac{i}{2}([x_j,p_k] - [x_k,p_j]) = \frac{i}{2}(i\delta_{jk} - i\delta_{kj}) \\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray}

Similarly you can prove that

$$
[a^\dagger_j, a^\dagger_k] = 0 ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ [a_j, a^\dagger_k] = \delta_{jk}
$$